# birix, циклический редирект на главной странице

Tags: php, битрикс, редирект

Переношу сайт с поддоменами на другой хостинг с помощью резервных копий и restore.php. Контент у поддоменов общий, а сами они реализованы ссылками, ссылаются на контент основного домена. После переноса зайт не запускается, постоянно происходит перенаправление на себя и подстановка в url имени старого домена, до тех пор, пока не происходит блокировка модулем веб-аналитики: http://bgazobeton.tmweb.ru/bgazobeton.ru/bgazobeton.ru/bgazobeton.ru/bgazobeton.ru/bgazobeton.ru/bgazobeton.ru/bgazobeton.ru/bgazobeton.ru/bgazobeton.ru/bgazobeton.ru
В админку зайти тоже не получается.
В .htaccess редиректов нет

Куда копать? Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Ну тут явно либо `apache`, либо `htaccess`, если у Вас в проекте никаких дополнительных редиректов нет. Можете дополнить вопрос указанными параметрами этих 2-х файлов?

Answer (score 0):

Случай оказался очень специфичным. Во всем виноват модуль "Регионы продаж", на нем была настроена куча поддоменов. При переносе нужно было сначала сделать редирект на уровне .htaccess с любого поддомена сайта на основной домен. Затем настроить символьные ссылки поддоменов и только потом переносить домен и базу данных. Тогда проблем с редиректом не будет